# Openlayers fit extent with bounce

Tags: animation, openlayers, extent

I am attempting to animate between two extents, with an increase in zoom during the middle of the animation, to create a bouncing or flying effect when going between locations which are far apart.  Right now I am using view.fit(extent, {duration: 2000}).  The problem is the zoom does not change at all during the animation.  When I am panning from one extent to another which are far apart, you just see a bunch of tiles flying by at a very low zoom level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a fly effect, you'll want to combine a `center` animation with two `zoom` animations, and start those at the same time. You can calculate the center and zoom from your desired extent (`myExtent`). Something like

```
    var resolution = view.getResolutionForExtent(myExtent);
    var zoom = view.getZoomForResolution(resolution);
    var center = ol.extent.getCenter(myExtent);
    view.animate({
      center: center,
      duration: duration
    });
    view.animate({
      zoom: zoom - 1,
      duration: duration / 2
    }, {
      zoom: zoom,
      duration: duration / 2
    });
```

Something similar is also shown as "Fly to Bern" in the official animation example (http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using a center, I want to fit the map to a certain extent.  Just using the center does not put me at my ideal resolution like I would like.

Comment: You can get the resolution for your desired extent with `ol.View#getResolutionForExtent`. I'm updating the code snippet in my answer.

Comment: Great, just what I needed.  Thanks!